# How can I exclude the links validation which were already validated?

Tags: java, selenium

below script i have to validate links on a page. Here is the twist, I need to validate links in this page plus need to click on each link then validate links on that page as well but I need to exclude links that were validated in the first page. I really do not know how to perform. I can do up to clicking on the link and validate the links in that page also but what code should i use to exclude those that were already validated. Please help if you can. Thanks

```
package siteLinks;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LinksValidation {
    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String homePage = "http://www.safeway.com/Shopstores/Site-Map.page";
        String url = "http://www.safeway.com/Shopstores/Site-Map.page";
        HttpURLConnection huc = null;
        int respCode = 200;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\aaarb00\\Desktop\\Quotients\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get(homePage);

        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        Iterator<WebElement> it = links.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){

            url = it.next().getAttribute("href");

            System.out.println(url);

            if(url == null || url.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("URL is either not configured for anchor tag or it is empty");
                continue;
            }

            try {
                huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url).openConnection());

                huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

                huc.connect();

                respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

                if(respCode >= 400){
                    System.out.println(url+" is a broken link");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(url+" is a valid link");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the links you've already visited in an ArrayList and check whether that ArrayList contains the link already.

```
ArrayList<String> visitedLinks = new ArrayList<String>();

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for(WebElement element : elements) {
    if(visitedLinks.contains(element.getAttribute("href"))) {
        System.out.println("Link already checked.  Not checking.");
    } else {
        visitedLinks.add(element.getAttribute("href"));
        // Your link checking code
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how you're checking the links off of the pages you check for a status 200 OK response, but you should probably define the URL for each page that you want to check the links on and then loop through those URLs.  Otherwise you're likely to exit the site you're checking links for and escape out onto the wider internet.  Your test is likely to never finish in that case.

Comment: Hi, I am pretty much new to this java thing and trying to catch up and learn. I am not able to run it and getting below error.

Comment: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Stale element references occur when the structure of the page changes in a way that makes elements you've already found no longer valid to interact with.  One of the most common causes of this is navigating away from a page, then trying to interact with a stored element.